# Intellij 12 - lock Junit configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I have to change my JUnit configuration because some system properties must be set. InteliJ removes those configurations sometimes, I suspect due to max configurations limit - this drives me really crazy!

Is it possible to lock particular configuration, so that it will not be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [Save the configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html) to make it persistent.

Another way it to increase the limit of temp configurations or put your options in the **Default** configuration.

Comment: What does it mean: "On the context menu of the editor or Project view, choose Save <configuration name>." ? I cannot find "context menu of the editor".....

Comment: That is just another way to save it in addition to the first 2 options, if a temp configuration can be created from the file context menu, you can also save if from the same menu.

Comment: I just do nit know how to call this context menu - on whar do I have to click? How do I navigate there?

Comment: Right click inside a file, you will get [this menu](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/3369/20130425191633.png), another option is to [use the save button](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/925/20130425191722.png).

Comment: thank you! Somehow my installation DOES not have "save" icon. Re-installation solved the problem.

Comment: May I create a permanent configuration for JUnit? I need this because my application's JUnit Test Config. needs Environment Variables and JUnit uses a new config. each time. I can not save a JUnit Config. and use it when I need because config. depends on the test methods. Thank you @CrazyCoder